# Is it possible to track conversions if user converts on a different page than the ad?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, tracking, conversions, goal-tracking

In google adwords, my client's conversion goal is contact form submission.

They're running ads on different pages of the website.

Is it possible to track the conversion if the site user takes a path like:

click ad --> go to "about page" --> click "contact" page --> submit form

Does adwords store data for the entire session to count this as a conversion? Or does the conversion have to happen on the same page, i.e. user has to be served the ad for the contact page, go directly there and submit the form?

Answer (score 1):

Analytics *should* track that, as the user's session would be attributable to the source/medium.

It would even track that if the user left and returned later (providing it was on a device that could be traced to that user, i.e. Google login or cookie). In such cases you can track this through multi-channel conversions.

I have witnessed examples where this hasn't been the case, though. Usually where the Google Ads attribution is lost due to how the website has been built (it was due to a conflict with the GTM code we were using instead of the universal tracking code).